# Distance between characters

Tags: bang

In Bang!, does the distance between characters decrease when a player is eliminated? Or, if a character is at a distance of 3 from you, will they always be a distance of 3 from you?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An eliminated player no longer contributes to distance.  If this were not the case, in a large game you could quite easily have situations where nobody could reach anybody else for many turns in a row.

From the [rules](http://www.dvgiochi.net/bang/bang_rules.pdf):

> When a character is eliminated, he is no longer counted when evaluating the distance: some players will get "closer" when someone is eliminated.